# Meaning of 「とかいった」 in this sentence?

Tags: grammar, translation

音無とかいったか俺はお前をまだ認めていない

I'm unsure how to properly break down this sentence. I believe that とか is to make using the name 音無 less direct. Is いった the past tense of いう?

It seems like a possible translation could be "Otonashi, I have yet to approve you". But then why would とかいう　be in the past tense?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this いった is the past form of 言う ("to say/call"), and か after it is a question marker. Isn't there a comma, a line break or a space after いったか? 音無とかいったか is "You said (something like) Otonashi?", and this is for confirming the listener's name. This sounds fairly blunt, so don't use it in conversations in real life.